# Fallback and optional dependencies in R packages the CRAN way?

Tags: r, dependencies, cran

I would like to add a fallback dependency to my package. Problem is I want to do it CRAN compliant and can't figure out how to do it properly.

More specificly, I want to use `data.table's fread / fwrite`. Other than that I do not want to have a full data.table dependency. If `data.table` is not installed, my package should just fall back to using standard `read.csv` and `write.csv`.

I've seen this similar thread: [Proper way to handle optional package dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545869/proper-way-to-handle-optional-package-dependencies)

and also used a technique similar to what @Hadley suggested in the comments:

```
req <- require(data.table)
if(req){ 
   data.table::fwrite(...)
 } else {
    write.csv(...)     

  }
```

This does work, but when running CHECK I get a NOTE:

`'library' or 'require' call to ‘data.table’ in package code.
  Please use :: or requireNamespace() instead.`

Which means I won't get it past CRAN's supervisors...

What's the correct way to handle this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just as the text says:

- replace your (outdated) call to `require()` with one to `requireNamespace()`
- Then, in the `TRUE` cases, call the package.
- I often use `::` to refer to the suggested package.

So mocking this up (and note, untested) I'd do

```
myreader <- function(file) {
    if (requireNamespace("data.table", quietly=TRUE)) {
       dat <- data.table::fread(file)
    } else {
       dat <- read.csv(file)
    }
    ## postprocess dat as needed
    dat
}
```

Searches at GitHub are useful with `user:cran l=R yourTerm` so try [this one](https://github.com/search?l=R&q=user%3Acran+requireNamespace&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93). I use the very idiom in a number of packages.

Comment: Neat. I did follow the message first, but was distracted by the 'error' message when entering a gibberish package name for testing. So, 2 things in this answer were helpful to me: 1. `quietly = TRUE` 2. that github search hint.

Comment: _De nada_. Thanks for catching the missing paren in the code riff I left there.